# PHP MYSQL search for specific lines

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a query only between some specific lines. (make a query where word = title, but the data only between line 8, line 9, line 10). But my code still turn back all the result.(it will print line 33, line 36 ...) How to make a right query? Thanks.

```
$where = " field_1 = '$word' OR field_2 = '$word' OR field_3 = '$word' ";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $where AND (id='8' OR id='9' OR id='10');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AND has higher precedence than OR so you need parentheses around `$where`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ($where) AND (id='8' OR id='9' OR id='10');
```

Without the parentheses it evaluates as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field_1 = '$word' OR
      field_2 = '$word' OR
      (field_3 = '$word' AND (id='8' OR id='9' OR id='10'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = " field_1 = '$word' OR field_2 = '$word' OR field_3 = '$word' ";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $where AND (id='8' OR id='9' OR id='10') LIMIT 8,3;
```

That should grab 3 records starting with line 8. Does that work?